# Check if Array of model structs contains a particular model value

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of struct like this:

```
var myGymData: [GymData] = []
```

`GymData` is a struct which conforms to `Codable` protocol.

Normally in Arrays, if you want to check if an element is already contained in the array, we do `myArray.contains(myData)`

But, in `myGymData` case, its an array of Struct, So the struct should conform to `Equatable` protocol.

How can I achieve it?

I need something like this:

```
let someData = GymData() 
if self.myGymData.contains(someData) { 
    print("already present")
} else {
    self.myGymData.append(someData)
}
```

Comment: How big does `myGymData` get, and how often are you trying to append to it? If the answer is big/often, then you should use a `Set` for better performance (`Set.contains(_:)` is only `O(1)` instead of the `O(n)` of the linear searching that `Array.contains(_:)` does.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But I am using pagination and only loading 10 data items at a time, so I think arrays can handle that. But yes, Sets can be really handy for this.

Comment: BDW, what's with "Reinstate Monica", I have seen many people on [so] trying to support her. What is it all about? I would like to know. Just share a link or something to let the reader of this post know what is it all about. THANKS.

Comment: That should probably be fine. I just wanted to point out that it's not just important how many times you check, but also how big the array gets. If you're paginating 10 at a time, that's probably fine. Though if you can bulk-load a bunch of items, and you end up doing `contains(_:)` calls on arrays with 1000s of items, that'll slow things considerably

Comment: Monica Cellio was an elected community mod that got fired for allegedly violating a code-of-conduct rule (one that was still being drafted, and not yet "live"), then got smeared over and over by the SO staff. TL;DR: SO now mandates that you use people's self-prescribed pronouns. Monica asked if it was okay to just not use any gendered pronouns, as is typical in professional writing. Apparently asking that was itself "bigoted" and a violation of the future code of conduct.

Comment: She learned about being fired by noticing she lost access to mod tools, without any direct communication, appeal process, or anything along those lines. The "Reinstate Monica" is a bit of a misnomer. I don't actually care if Monica gets reinstated (idk if she would currently even want that), I just want SO to acknowledge the SNAFU and make amends of some description, and to stop heavy-handedly imposing their niche America-centric Bay-area politics on their international platform. To be clear, they have the right to do so, but we also have a right to not be happy about it.

Comment: That's about as best as I can sum it up. If you're interested in further detail, she goes through a full play-by-play of what happened, in this hour long podcast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After conforming to `Equatable`, implement `==(lhs:rhs:)` method. In this method return `true/false` based on the condition of equality of the `GymData` instances.

```
struct GymData: Equatable {
    let name: String

    static func == (lhs: GymData, rhs: GymData) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
let x = GymData(name: "A")
let y = GymData(name: "B")
let z = GymData(name: "A")

let myGymData = [x]

myGymData.contains(x) //true
myGymData.contains(y) //false
myGymData.contains(z) //true
```

Comment: You know that since Swift 4.1 `static func ==` is synthesized in structs.

Comment: @vadian I am using Swift 5.7 on Monterey and Xcode tells me I have to have static.